# How to save NSMutablearray in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have two `NSMutableArray`'s. They consist of images or text.
The arrays are displayed via a `UITableView`.
When I kill the app the data within the `UITableView` gets lost.
How to save array in `UITableView` by using `NSUserDefault`?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Note: NSUserDefaults will always return an immutable version of the object you pass in.

**To store the information:**

```
// Get the standardUserDefaults object, store your UITableView data array against a key, synchronize the defaults
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:arrayOfImage forKey:@"tableViewDataImage"];
[userDefaults setObject:arrayOfText forKey:@"tableViewDataText"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

**To retrieve the information:**

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayOfImages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"tableViewDataImage"];
NSArray *arrayOfText = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"tableViewDataText"];
// Use 'yourArray' to repopulate your UITableView
```

On first load, check whether the result that comes back from `NSUserDefaults` is `nil`, if it is, you need to create your data, otherwise load the data from `NSUserDefaults` and your `UITableView` will maintain state.

**Update**

In Swift-3, the following approach can be used:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

userDefaults.set(arrayOfImage, forKey:"tableViewDataImage")
userDefaults.set(arrayOfText, forKey:"tableViewDataText")
userDefaults.synchronize()

var arrayOfImages = userDefaults.object(forKey: "tableViewDataImage")
var arrayOfText = userDefaults.object(forKey: "tableViewDataText")
```

Comment: Your question asked how to store Arrays in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: "NSUserDefaults will always return an immutable version" was the answer in my case. Thank you very much!

Comment: Swift 3 doesn't need to perform `synchronize`

Answer (score 45):

You can save your mutable array like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourArray forKey:@"YourKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Later you get the mutable array back from user defaults. It is important that you get the mutable copy if you want to edit the array later.

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"YourKey"] mutableCopy];
```

Then you simply set the `UITableview` data from your mutable array via the `UITableView` delegate

Hope this helps!

Comment: You just declare 2 different mutable arrays and save them for different keys in the user defaults.

Comment: If i use this code arrays are not load in UITableview. it show null value in nslog

Comment: As I wrote you will set the ui table view data via the ui table view delegate. Read this one: http://tech.pro/tutorial/1026/how-to-create-and-populate-a-uitableview

Comment: Thank you, you are a life saver. The "mutableCopy" bit at the end is vital. Otherwise even if you store the data back in an NSMutableArray, the contents will still be immutable. Thanks so much :)

Comment: [Note: It is not necessary to call `synchronize` every time you set an `NSUserDefault`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647931/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method)

Answer (score 7):

I want just to add to the other answers that the object that you are going to store store in the `NSUserDefault`, as reported in the Apple documentation must be conform to this:

"The value parameter can be only property list objects: `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects."

here the link to [property list programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)

so pay attention about what is inside your array

Answer (score 3):

Do you really want to store images in property list? You can save images into files and store filename as value in `NSDictionary`.

define path for store files

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
self.basePath = [paths firstObject];
```

Store and load image:

```
- (NSString *)imageWithKey:(NSString)key {
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", key]
    return [self.basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}

- (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withKey:(NSString)key {
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:[self imageWithKey:key] atomically:YES];
}

- (UIImage *)loadImageWithKey:(NSString)key { {
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self imageWithKey:key]];
}
```

And you can store path or indexes in `NSMutableDictionary`

```
- (void)saveDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictForSave = [@{ } mutableCopy];
    for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
        [self saveImageWithKey:key];
        dictForSave[key] = @{ @"image" : key };
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictForSave forKey:@"MyDict"];
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)loadDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    NSDictionary *loadedDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyDict"];
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [@{ } mutableCopy];
    for (NSString *key in [loadedDict allKeys]) {
        result[key] = [self imageWithKey:key];
    }
    return result;
}
```

In `NSUserDefaults` you can store only simply objects like `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`.

Also you can serialize objects with `NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver` that conforms to NSCoding protocol .

Answer (score 3):

**Save:**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(PickedArray, forKey: "myArray")
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Retrieve:**

```
if let PickedArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("myArray") {
    print("SUCCCESS:")
    println(PickedArray)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add strings to the `NSMutableArray` in ant specific order, or if you are using the `NSMutableArray` for a `UITableView` you may want to use this instead:

```
[NSMutableArray insertObject:string atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, for an NSMutableArray, you will need to encode/decode your array to be able to save it/ retrieve it in NSUserDefaults :

**Saving**

```
//Encoding array
let encodedArray : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myMutableArray) as NSData

//Saving
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.setValue(encodedArray, forKey:"myKey")
defaults.synchronize()
```

**Retrieving**

```
//Getting user defaults
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

//Checking if the data exists
if defaults.data(forKey: "myKey") != nil {
   //Getting Encoded Array
   let encodedArray = defaults.data(forKey: "myKey")

   //Decoding the Array
   let decodedArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encodedArray!) as! [String]
}
```

**Removing**

```
//Getting user defaults
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

//Checking if the data exists
if defaults.data(forKey: "myKey") != nil {

    //Removing the Data
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: "myKey")

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Save information of Array in `NSUserdefaults` with key.

"MutableArray received from JSON response"

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:statuses forKey:@"arrayListing"];
```

"Retrieve this information(Array) anywhere in the project with same key"

```
NSArray *arrayList = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"arrayListing"];
```

This helped me in my project and hope, it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Swift Version:

Save Array in NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(selection, forKey: "genderFiltersSelection")
```

Retrieve Bool Array From NSUserDefaults:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("genderFiltersSelection") != nil{
                selection = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("genderFiltersSelection") as? [Bool] ?? [Bool]()
   }
```

Retrieve String Array From NSUserDefaults:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("genderFiltersSelection") != nil{
                selection = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("genderFiltersSelection") as? [String] ?? [String]()
    }
```