# iOS: Saving NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults give me an error : 'Attempt to insert non-property list object'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, compiler-errors

I am wondering how it is possible to save NSMutableArray in an NSUserDefaults? I keep getting the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "<Data: 0x7a1bf830>",
) for key dataList'
```

Here is my code

```
   NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                                initWithSuiteName:@"group.sharingData"];
  [myDefaults setObject:self.dataList forKey:@"dataList"];
  [myDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: check this [thread][1] it describes how to add an array to NSUserdefaults


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634426/how-to-save-nsmutablearray-in-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `self.dataList` contains an object of type `Data` (which is a custom class of your implementation).

You need to switch to `NSData` or convert the `Data` objects to property list objects.

Comment: Or make your objects `NSCoding` compatible to use `NSKeyedArchiver` for serialization/deserialization needs

Comment: @JustSid Making objects conform to `NSCoding` is not enough to put them in `NSUserDefaults`. You also have to do the conversion to `NSData` manually.

Comment: Didn't I mention `NSKeyedArchiver` for serialization/deserialization needs?